# How to animate fragment to stay at right of the screen

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I have an activity in the landscape mode and on some button click the fragment appears. it adds up but to the left of the screen.
But i want to add it to the right of the screen and close it to the right itself.

I am unable to have appropriate animations. 
How do i do this?

Comment: and how do i set the background as greyed and onclicking the portion outside fragment the fragment should be closed ????

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

slide-in-right

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

slide-out-left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

both in res/anim folder

Comment: hi, i already had this solution but it slides the fragment to the left border while i want to slide it in from left and stick it to the right of the screen .. similar animation like drawer but from right to right